# Local file path does't work in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an issue with my inline javascript which is in html page.

I'm using following code in the javascript.

`ifrm.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///C:/Project-2/parent.css">');`

This works perfectly fine on all the browsers, but not with Chrome.

Is there any workaround?

Thanks

Comment: try using relative paths

Comment: Hi,
Any suggestion with code as how to use relative path instead of local path?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes relative paths would be the way to go here. As of right now if you tried to deploy this page to the web then none of the links would work (assuming you're referencing files that reside on your PC via absolute paths).

Here is some good material explaining absolute vs. relative pathing: http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/